# Need help checking if my CFG question is correct

Tags: regex, computer-science, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

I need to write a CFG for the language below:

`L = { w ∈ Σ* | w is a regular expression over a binary alphabet }`

I came up with:

S = SΣ* | ε

X = S | ε

I'm starting the discipline now, and if it isn't correct, i would apreciate an explanation.
Many thanks!

PS.: This is not part from a homework, it is just an exercise from a Computer Science Theory book.

ANSWER BASED ON Mo B. POST

S = e | {0,1}

X = S | S* | Z

Y = X | YX

Z = Y | Z | Y

SECOND ANSWER BASED ON Mo B. POST

S = e | {0,1}

X = S | S'*' | '(' Z ')'

Y = X | YX

Z = Y | Z '|' Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not correct. The language is the set of *regular expressions* (which itself isn't regular, but it's luckily context-free), so you need to come up with a context-free grammar for regular expressions. (First, make sure you know the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) for regular expressions.)

The meta-alphabet Σ has not been defined in your question, but it only works if Σ at least contains the mentioned binary alphabet, say 0 and 1, and the symbols `ε`, `*`, `|`, `(` and `)`.

Here is one way of doing it:

```
Basic   ::= 'ε'   // Note that this is the symbol 'ε' which is not the same as ε
          | c     // for c in {0, 1} or whatever the binary alphabet is
Star    ::= Basic
          | Star '*'
          | '(' Regular ')'
Concat  ::= Star
          | Concat Star
Regular ::= Concat
          | Regular '|' Concat
```

Comment: I didnt downvoted your answer. Actually, many thanks for it, i haven't enough reputation to upvote you. Could you help me with the right answer for this one? Thanks.

Comment: @beto99 Well, this *is* the right answer. Or is there anything still unclear?

Comment: Mo B., check if the answer on my question is the same thing of yours, please.

Comment: Almost, but not quite. You need to make sure to distinguish symbols from meta-symbols, e.g. "|", "*", "(", ")" or "ε". Use apostrophes to make the distinction. Secondly, your second case is missing the brackets "(" and ")".

Comment: Mo B., many thanks. I think we finally did it.

Comment: @MoB.: Derive `(a|b)*` from that grammar. If you can do so, I'll retract the dv.

Comment: @rici Thanks for the hint. I've corrected the bug. When you downvote, please add a comment unless the reason is obvious. Otherwise it's not really helpful.